# What is the preferred way of searching for content in source code using JS?

Tags: javascript, html, comments

I have a JavaScript statement on the bottom of my page that I want to trigger ONLY if a certain HTML comment is available

```
<!-- mytriggercomment -->
```

In the above example, if the `mytriggercomment` is detected within the current page, only then should the JavaScript statement trigger. What is the preferred way of doing this?

Comment: `yourHTMLstring.indexOf('<!-- mytriggercomment -->') !== -1` doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May not work for older browsers, but this way is a logical DOM approach:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
<script>
window.onload = function () {
   var treeWalker = document.createTreeWalker(
      document,
      NodeFilter.SHOW_COMMENT,
      {acceptNode: function(node) {
          if (node.nodeValue.trim() === 'mytriggercomment') {
              return NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT;
          }
      }}
    );
    var nodeList = [];

    while(treeWalker.nextNode()) nodeList.push(treeWalker.currentNode);

    alert(nodeList)
};
</script></head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
<!-- mytriggercomment -->
```

If you know it will always be at the bottom, you may be able to target it like:

```
window.onload = function () {

    alert(document.documentElement.nextSibling && 
        document.documentElement.nextSibling.nodeValue.trim() === 'mytriggercomment')

};
```